# Is ‘on (in) a tear’ a popular idiom?

Tags: phrases, idioms, contemporary-english

I was drawn to the phrase, ‘on a tear,’ which I heard in audio in this week’s Barron’s magazine (June 6), reporting the good sales and profit performance of U.S. sneaker chain, Foot Locker:

It says:

> Foot Locker is proving that expansion isn’t everything. The sneaker chain’s sales per square foot have been **on a tear** even as the company’s store count shrinks. That‘s done wonders for Foot Locker’s profit margins and stock price.

As I’m unfamiliar with the idiom, ‘on a tear,’ I consulted English dictionaries in both print and online.

The Cambridge, Oxford, and Merriam-Webster English dictionaries and the Oxford American Dictionary do not carry ‘on a tear’ as an idiom. I suspected it could be “in a tier,” but it doesn’t add up in the context.

However, I found ‘on a tear’ in Collins English Dictionary and urban dictionary.

Collins defines ‘on a tear’ as;

> (slang) showing a sudden burst of energy. ex. Final domestic demand, then, was *on a tear* —— good news.

Urban Dictionary defines it as;

> on a streak or series, usually a winning streak. Will sometimes be used semi-sarcastically to define a losing streak. ex. The market went up 14% in the least four weeks. The market is *on a tear*! –

And, Google Ngram shows that the usages of both ‘on a tear’ and ‘in a tear’ have been observed since early before 1840. The incidences of ‘on a tear’ is on rise from 0.000001 in 1970 to 0.0000025 after 2000 and onward, but incidences of 'in a tear' have been flattened out at the low level of 0.0000012 - 0.0000016 throughout the tracked period.

Now here are my questions:

1. What is the plain and exact meaning of ‘on (in) a tear’ in the context of the above quote?
2. Is ‘on (in) a tear’ a popular idiom?
3. Why none of major English dictionaries such as CED, OED, OALED, MWED accommodates this phrase as an idiom in spite of a long presence of the phrase as shown in Google NGram?

**Addendum:**

The Barrons’ magazine seems to be fond of using "on a tear."  It repeated this phrase again in its June 19 news-report (through AFN radio broadcast) reporting a marked improvement of U.S.'s largest closeout chain, Big Lots’ sales performance. It says

> (the chain’s) Sales growth in Canada is **on a tear**. Any signs of the progress will likely allure investors back to Big Lots.

Comment: I'm familiar with _on_, but _in_ looks new to me. Then again, this happens to prepositions from time to time.

Comment: Note that basically all the older (19th-century) hits for _on a tear_ refer to the Complete Works of Lord Byron where a poem (I presume?) named _On a Tear_ by someone called Mr. Rogers is mentioned. This could well be a tear /tir/ rather than a tear /tɛr/. There are probably other false hits too, like “X is located _on a tear_ fault in the Appalachians”, etc.

Comment: "On a tear" does indeed appear in Merriam Webster under the definition of "tear" a a noun.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*In a tear* (or *on a tear*) does appear in OED:

> **3b.** A spree *(U.S. slang)*.
>
> 1896   *Harper's Mag.* Apr. 775/2   Got me off on a tear somehow, and by the time I was sober again the money was 'most all gone.

and

> Draft additions 1993
>
> A spree; in *Sport,* a successful run, a winning streak; esp. in phr. ***on a tear.*** *U.S. slang.*

The quote may be explained as

> Foot Locker is proving that expansion isn’t everything. The sneaker chain’s sales per square foot have been ***rocketing*** even as the company’s store count shrinks. That’s done wonders for Foot Locker’s profit margins and stock price.

As to your other questions, the answer is that *in a tear* in that sense is probably not all that common, which is why it's not included in dictionaries. Google Ngrams may be misleading, because a large number of results will be for the lachrymal *tear-stained* or for a literal tear (=split, rent).

Comment: Illuminating answer. What is the pronunciation of the word "tear" in this idiom?

Comment: @Irene: _tear_ here rhymes with _air_, not _ear_.

Comment: There's a British English expression "to be on the tear" which is fairly common and means "out to party/get drunk" e.g. "I finished my exams so I'm going out on the tear tonight"

Comment: @J.R., I agree it doesn't rhyme with *ear* but *air* isn't quite flat enough.  More like *tare*.  Wiktionary shows *[air](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/air#Pronunciation)* and *[tare](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tare#Pronunciation)* both rhyming with -ɛə(r) but I suggest diphthong [-eə(r)](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/pron/sounds/vowel_dip_6.shtml) for *tare* and this use of *tear*

Comment: @jwpat: There are the _tears_ we get from chopping onions (rhymes with _ears_) and the _tears_ we get in our notebook paper (rhymes with _airs_). As you know, there are two ways to pronounce *tear*; when Irene asked her question, I assumed she was asking which of those two pronunciations were used in the expression _on a tear_. I was only trying to disambiguate in a straightforward way; I wasn't trying to write a precise pronunciation guide. Regional accents may vary. :^)

Comment: I'm familiar with "on a tear" meaning on a winning streak or run of great success. I wouldn't say it was that unusual. (Native Brit, and for me tear rhymes exactly with air)

Answer (score 1):

To pull a part, divide by force. The denotation paints the picture of the connotation: one is ripping through an expected obstacle or opponent which can be to the upside or down. Most often, the usage appears to the upside or in a positive direction.

While the usage may seem as slang, it is just an artful use of a well defined word into a term clearly understood by most.

It is not possible to be in a tear.

Not every common, or common sense, use of a word or term is documented as an idiom. If you catch my drift.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that most of these answers are correct to a degree. I became interested in the phrase after coming across it in the folk-song "Mick Maguire". Here is the last verse (or last refrain):
*Johnny come up to the fire come up you're sitting in the draught/
Can't you see it's ould Maguire and he nearly drives me daft/
Sure I don't know what gets into him and he's always on the tear/
So sit where you are and never you dare, to give ould Maguire the chair*

In this context - and the context of the rest of the song - its meaning would be "ranting and complaining". It's possible it could be "drunk" but it seems unlikely to me, as there are no references to drink.

Answer (score 0):

At least in the field of economy, investment and finance, the term: on the tear, is widely used to describe a burst, a quick rise of stock prices, etc. See:
For those of you who haven’t noticed, emerging markets have been on a tear.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple meanings to this idiom. There is "on a winning streak" which I take to be meant by your quote and also "drunk"/"on a drunken spree", both of which have already been described. However, I have also heard this phrase used to mean something more like ***"ranting and raving"*** or ***"righteously indignant"***. (I would pronounce "tear" in this usage to rhyme with wear or bear rather than year or fear.)

"On a tear" is the more common formulation, but with this usage, I believe, "*in* a tear" is sometimes used—I associate "in a tear" with old-fashioned, Southern, or "countrified" American vernacular, while "on a tear" doesn't have that connotation for me.

For example:

> "Reed had learned to respect Sylvie Morrisette, even if he did have to
>   walk on eggshells upon occasion. This morning she was flush in the
>   face and looked as if she could spit nails. . . . Her west-Texas drawl
>   was stronger than ever when she was **on a tear** and she was on a
>   major one this morning. 'Bastard. That's what he is! A card-carrying,
>   dyed-in-the-wool, fucking bastard.'" —[*Unspoken* by Lisa Jackson](https://books.google.com/books?id=m1KtQ0ieqkgC&pg=PA372&dq=%22she%20was%20on%20a%20tear%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjsgsWltrnNAhUYKFIKHanpAF8Q6AEIHjAA#v=onepage&q=%22she%20was%20on%20a%20tear%22&f=false)

and

> "' . . . I'm not going to write twentieth-century drivel. What do you
>   want? Another rerun of "Ozzie and Harriet" or "Leave it to Beaver"?'
>   She was **on a tear**. 'Earth to Maynard, turn off the TV. "Cheers" is
>   dated bullshit. . . .'" —[*Women of Harvard Square* by Michael
>   Lieberman](https://books.google.com/books?id=Kb5OBQAAQBAJ&lpg=PT62&dq=%22she%20was%20on%20a%20tear%22&pg=PT62#v=onepage&q=%22she%20was%20on%20a%20tear%22&f=false)

For "in a tear":

> "First she was complainin' about how William Allers was gonna marry
>   Alice Hagginbotham, after Chloe thought he'd been courtin' her for the
>   past few months. Well, she was **in a tear**." —[*Letters from the Trail*
>   by Emily Winters](https://books.google.com/books?id=EAddAgAAQBAJ&pg=PT28&dq=%22she%20was%20in%20a%20tear%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi1pL_ItbnNAhVGc1IKHZuUCskQ6AEIIDAA#v=onepage&q=%22she%20was%20in%20a%20tear%22&f=false) (note that it is clear from the larger context
>   that this does not mean Chloe was crying)

and

> "'I have a bit of a headache, that's all. Mama was **in a tear** this
>   morning.' That explained everything. Mama **in a tear** was worse than a
>   barrel of ale for making your head ache." —[Sweet Disorder by Rose
>   Lerner](https://books.google.com/books?id=6YJmAQAAQBAJ&lpg=PA32&dq=%22was%20in%20a%20tear%22&pg=PA33#v=onepage&q=%22was%20in%20a%20tear%22&f=false)

and

> "'Morons!' Terry was **in a tear**. Her outburst surprised me. She was
>   taking this almost as personally as I was." —[*Lost and Found* by Mary
>   Lou Quinn](https://books.google.com/books?id=n2OfBAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA172&dq=%22was%20in%20a%20tear%22&pg=PA172#v=onepage&q=%22was%20in%20a%20tear%22&f=false)

Hmm, looking at these examples (not cherry-picked) it appears that "in a tear" is a gendered phrase, used more often by female authors and describing almost exclusively female characters. I find no Google Books results at all for "he was in a tear" and most of the results for "he was on a tear" are using the winning streak or drunken idioms. A search for "was in a tear" turned up only the above three quotes, all by and about women, and "she was on a tear" shows examples of the usage I've described in all of the quotes visible on the [first page of results](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&hl=en&q=%22she%20was%20on%20a%20tear%22). I wonder if this gendered split in usage holds true in spoken English, as well (I'm female, and this is the first definition that springs to mind for me, not the sports or drinking definitions).

Answer (score 0):

I have often heard the phrase "on a tare" my entire life, growing up in the south. We always use it to refer to a person who is really mad/upset for an extended period of time. "Her husband bought her a vacuum for Valentine's Day, so she's been on a tare all week."

Comment: I think the correct spelling is tear, not tare. If you correct this it makes the answer an interesting observation.

Answer (score -1):

"On a tear" means doing a lot of something or doing something with unusual intensity or frequency. 
Also never say "IN a tear." Only ON.  IN A TEAR is not colloquial.

Comment: Answers are much better when they actually address the OP's question. He understands (and defined) the idiom.

Answer (score -1):

I always believed it was "on a tare" referring to empty trucks (at tare weight) that have delivered their loads and are now barreling down the highway towards home, not struggling with hills and curves, full speed ahead.

Comment: Do you have any reference to support your answer?